# About public parameters in AWS Parameter Store

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I'm wondering about how to make a parameter stored in **AWS Parameter Store** public to other AWS accounts. I found [Working with public parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/parameter-store-public-parameters.html) article in AWS documentation, but it seems that *public parameters* are something only directly managed by AWS.

Is there a way to store a parameter in the **Parameter Store** in a way it is accessible to other AWS accounts or should I fallback on some solution like a public **S3 Bucket** containing **S3 Items** used as key/value pairs containing the parameters I want to make public?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid public SSM parameters are indeed just AWS native readonly ones.

You can however utilize STS in your child account to assume a role in your parent account to query Parameter Store. I did not quite find an article directly for Parameter Store, but here is one for Secrets Manager https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/design-patterns-to-access-cross-account-secrets-stored-in-aws-secrets-manager/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I prefer to not adopt this solution because I'm already in an STS Session when I need to access parameters from another account. Anyway it's good alternative solution.